# Validate if input is coordinate c#

Tags: c#, regex

i have to validate if given input string is valid cordinate or not

```
 string s1 = "78;58|98;52";
```

This is valid cordinate is "78;58|98;52" => "Width;Height|X,Y"

Comment: what is valid coordinate? like a group of number separated by ; and | for another set of numbers

Comment: please add some more information to your question. Furthermore, some examples  of your attempts would be good.

Comment: Show some samples like what are valid and what are invalid

Comment: updated question for which value is valid

Comment: what are the ranges of width, height, x, y?

Comment: When describing a input validation look for edge case. Do you accept negative value? Do you accept decimal?Classical coordinate are Double here you show int..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern: `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?);(?1)\|(?1);(?1)`.

`(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` matches numbers: integers or decimal numbers, where decimal character is `.` (dot).

`(?1)` - references above pattern to match it four times.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/evqZEV/1)

Try this code:

```
string[] coords = { "78;58|98;54", "78.1;58.23|98;54.12", "78;58.23|98.13;54" };

Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?;?){2}|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?;?){2}");

foreach (string coord in coords)
    if (regex.Match(coord).Success)
        MessageBox.Show($"Success with string {coord}");
```

It uses `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?;?){2}|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?;?){2}` as pattern, since I couldn't figure out how to backreference pattern in C#. It's just first pattern expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(\d+;\d+)\|(\d+;\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rfrUrg/2)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example for a coordinate validation program. You can easily change the validation logic. Furthermore, the input string for the coordinate constructor needs to be checked.

```
class Coordinate
{
    public int Width { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }

    public Coordinate(string str)
    {
        // Validate str and/or p and check of the TryParse was successful
        var p = str.Split(new char[] { ';', '|' }).Select(x =>
        {
            int.TryParse(x, out int res);
            return res;
        });

        Width = p.ElementAt(0);
        Height = p.ElementAt(1);
        X = p.ElementAt(2);
        Y = p.ElementAt(3);
    }
}

static class CoordinateValidator
{
    public static bool isValidCoordinate(Coordinate coordinate)
    {
        // Here add your validation Logic
        return coordinate.Height > 0 && coordinate.Width > 0;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "78;58|98;52";
    Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(s);
    Console.WriteLine("Is valid: " + CoordinateValidator.isValidCoordinate(coordinate));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    if (Regex.IsMatch(s1, @"^\d+;\d+\|\d+;\d+$")) {
        // Successful match
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

If you want to limit the amount of digits accepted you only need to replace + by {1,2} or {1,3} to accept 1 up-to 3 digits